# Angular and Node + Express

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I can only see a method to run Angular on one terminal and Node+Express on another.

Is there a way to combine these two so that when I deploy to the cloud I can run only one instance?

Comment: Your question is not that clear. Anyway, I am guessing what you're looking for is a way to run multiple terminal commands in a single terminal. If so, please read this article.
https://linuxhint.com/run_multiple_commands_linux/

Comment: Run multiple node servers on different ports, why is that a problem? Depending on number on cores on the instance you can choose to increase the number from 2 to more, you can make containers or choose to use a process manager too.

Comment: For instance in Flask, I could serve static files and run just one process. Is there an equivalent with Node? send_static_files or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

@Latcie You could use concurrent commands runner module like `concurrently` to achieve this.

```
npm i concurrently
```